# Parse JSON to nested array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, node.js, reactjs

I have a ReactJS from, in which the user uploads both, images and text input.
The form is seperated into a dynamic amount of sections, which all contain the same kind of information like so:

```
<div>
    <input placeholder="Name of the author" />
    <input type="file" />
    <input placeholder="Age of the author" />
</div>
```

I used to do `JSON.stringify()` to send the data to my node.js backend and to save them to my database, however, since I now allow file-uploads as well, I have to use `FormData()`. When I used `JSON.stringify()`, it saved my neatly as an array of objects, but now that doesn't work anymore and I simply get an array of strings.

First of all the relevant code of my ReactJS frontend:

```
class Form extends React.Component {
    constructor (props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            formdata : [
                {author : "name", age: 1},
                {author : "othername", age: 144}
            ]
        }
    }
    onSubmit = (e) => {

    let formData = new FormData();

    for (var i = 0; i < formdata.length; i++) {
        formData.append('formdata', JSON.stringify(formdata[i]));
    }

    axios.post('newauthor',
        formData)
        .then(function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
    }

render() {
    return(
        <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit} encType="multipart/form-data">
        //Content see above
        </form>
    )
}

And in node.js I save the formdata to my database like so:

NewEntry.formdata = req.body.data;
```

But this returns an array of JSON objects like so:

```
[{"author" : "name", "age": 1},{"author" : "othername", "age": 144}]
```

However, I need to use that data later and up until now, I could just map through the data and use the name of the object to get the value. I read several questions about this topic but nothing helped. I also tried `JSON.parse` but for some reason this always gave me an error (it gave me different errors, one of them was that there was an unexpected character in JSON at position 1).
So, how can I transform a JSON string into an array of objects?

Comment: What is `data`? upon which you are iterating inside submit? I cannot see it defined anywhere!

Comment: You are iterating something, I guess it is the array of objects, and append each item to the `formData` with same `name`, so the next item will overwrite the previous one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer is, a part of your `formData` is stringified not the entire formdata.
You are iterating over some object and applying `JSON.stringify` on each element.
Here:

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        formData.append('data', JSON.stringify(data[i]));
    }
```

But while parsing, you are trying to parse, `JSON.parse`, the entire `formdata`.

Instead, before sending the data to server, for `JSON.parse` you need to `stringify` the `formdata` data itself.

Change you axios pst code to:

```
axios.post('newauthor',{data: JSON.stringify(formData)}
        )
        .then(function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        })
```

Second of all there is so much wrong with your code.

Like: Inside the `constructor` state is not defined correctly, there is a missing `comma`.

How is this even compiling, there is a missing comma after first element.

```
this.state = {
            formdata : [
                {author : "name", age: 1}
                {author : "othername", age: 144}
            ]
        }
```

and you should not use arrow function inside class declaration, I am not sure how is this working for you!

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply! These errors aren't in my actual code, I quickly typed that up because I would've had to delete so much from my actual code. I'll pay attention to make less mistakes next time and again, thank you!

Comment: I lost my files from yesterday (where it worked) and now it tells me that it can't read the property "length" of undefined (as I mentioned in the post, there were also file inputs) and I'm assuming that's because I user `JSON.stringify()` on all of the data, including the files. Do you have a solution for that? I also tried `formData.append("data", JSON.stringify(data));` and `formData.append("data", {data: JSON.stringify(data)});` but it didn't work.

Comment: Okay I think I fixed it, in my node file, I simply did `NewEntry.formdata=JSON.parse(req.body.data)`, not sure if that's a good solution